# Excel VBA won't replace SharePoint link in HTML body of email

Tags: excel, vba, html-email

I wrote this macro to send out reminder emails from a template. I used the exact macro to populate another email and it replaces the SharePoint URL perfectly but a literal copy/paste of this macro to use for this email and it will not replace the reference to %Sharepoint Link%, it does everything else. Can anyone suggest something else I can try?

```
Sub Send_Reminder_Email()

Call Define

EmailList.Select
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    x = LastRow
    
For i = 2 To x

'info for each email
EOEmail = Range("C" & i)
SMSEmail = Range("D" & i)
toSMO = "me@fake.com"
ReportingPeriod = Range("B" & i)
EOName = Range("E" & i)
Materiality = Range("F" & i)
EngagementName = Range("A" & i)
SPLink = Range("G" & i).Value
SMSLead = Range("H" & i)
DueDate = Range("I" & i)

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olMail = olApp.createitemfromtemplate("X:fakepath\fakeemail.msg")


With olMail
    .To = EOEmail
    .cc = SMSEmail
    .bcc = toSMO
    .Subject = Replace(.Subject, "<Reporting Period>", ReportingPeriod)
    .htmlbody = Replace(olMail.htmlbody, "%EO Name%", EOName)
    .htmlbody = Replace(olMail.htmlbody, "%materiality%", Materiality)
    .htmlbody = Replace(olMail.htmlbody, "%Engagement Name%", EngagementName)
    '***this is not working***
    .htmlbody = Replace(olMail.htmlbody, "%Sharepoint Link%", "<a href=" & SPLink & ">here</a>")
    '***
    .htmlbody = Replace(olMail.htmlbody, "%Due Date%", DueDate)
    .htmlbody = Replace(olMail.htmlbody, "%SMS Lead%", SMSLead)
    .sentonbehalfofname = toSMO
    .display
'   .send
End With

Set otlmail = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

Next

MsgBox ("Done.")

End Sub
```

Comment: If that's the only part failing then it seems like "%Sharepoint Link%" was not found in the HTMLbody.

Comment: Hi Tim, I've copied/paste the exact spelling with the %% into the email template and still have the same issue.

Comment: So you still see `%Sharepoint Link%` after running the code?  It's difficult to guess why it's not working without access to the template you're using.

Comment: Yes the macro will replace everything else but '%Sharepoint Link%' . Apologies in advance if i'm not posting the text to the template correctly but this is what's in the body of the email message. ***Hi %EO Name%,

Please be advised a Performance Monitoring Attestation is outstanding for %materiality% engagement %Engagement Name%. Please complete the attestation and upload supporting evidence %Sharepoint Link% by %Due Date%.

Please contact %SMS Lead% if you have any questions and/or concerns.***

Comment: Can you share the actual template file (or a redacted one which has the same problem)?